# Union of N intersecting translucent 3D objects

Tags: opengl, depth-buffer, openscenegraph, stencil-buffer

I confused with the problem of intersecting translucent 3D objects.

I have a plenty of translucent objects which (potentially) can intersect each other. So, when I'm displayng them, in the case of intersection happened, I can see common parts of intersected objects inside each other.

What I want to do is to hide this common parts while rendering is being performed (it should looks like as a union of objects).

I'm new to OpenGL, but I've done some research and found that potentially it could be done by playing with Stencil/Depth/Color buffers and multi-rendering.

I wonder if someone can give me some advises about this proccess or techniques. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want any shading on them?

Comment: @HenkDeBoer at this moment shading is not critical, so I think the answer is no

Comment: Well if it stays no, you could consider rendering all translucent objects as opaque to an offscreen buffer, then render the total buffer back to the main buffer with a certain opacity. keep in mind that without shading, it may be very hard for the viewer to properly see depth in your scene if you go this way.

Comment: @HenkDeBoer oh, I see, and what if later I'll need shading? The proccess will be another?

Comment: If this sounds like a bad idea, try a depth prepass before you render. This way only the foremost triangles are rendered. It becomes a little more complicated if you have other non-translucent objects that should be visible intersecting the translucent ones. Perhaps make a picture of what you have in mind :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100677/discussion-between-tema-and-henk-de-boer).